# COCO dataset number of images per classes

Tags: neural-network, coco

I see COCO2017 has 80 classes 118k training and 5k validation dataset(122k images).
I have a question here. Does the number of images per classes(1525 images per class) which is ~ 122k / 80?

Answer (score 2):

the COCO dataset is not an evenly distributed dataset, i.e., all the classes *do not* have the same number of images. So, let me show you a way to find out the number of images in any class you wish.

I am using the [PyCoco API](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/tree/master/PythonAPI) to work with the COCO dataset. Let's find out the number of images in the 'person' class of the COCO dataset. Here is a code gist to filter out any class from the COCO dataset:

```
# Define the class (out of the 80 COCO classes)
filterClasses = ['person']

# Fetch class IDs only corresponding to the filterClasses
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=filterClasses) 

# Get all images containing the above Category IDs
imgIds = coco.getImgIds(catIds=catIds)
print("Number of images containing the class:", len(imgIds))
```

There, we get the number of images corresponding to 'person' in the dataset!

I have recently written an entire post on [exploring and manipulating the COCO dataset](https://towardsdatascience.com/master-the-coco-dataset-for-semantic-image-segmentation-part-1-of-2-732712631047). Do have a look to get more details and the entire code.